# All the USB ports on one physical side don't work after suspend

Tags: linux, usb, hardware-failure, suspend

I have a new problem with my Lenovo Edge E545 where, after suspending and resuming, 1 USB-2.0 port and 2 USB-3.0 ports fail to work. They are all the USB ports on the same physical side of the computer. This is on Linux, and is a new problem. It fixes on reboot. How do I diagnose and fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with windows. This is how I fixed it: Devices -> USB hub-> properties -> power management -> untick: Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power. Check if your linux distro has similar functionality as the PC may not be restoring power the ports on resume.

Comment: Sure, it does... only it seems the bus on that side doesn't RE-power. The USB port on the other side does re-power.